# View folder not being copied by dotnet publish

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.0 multiproject solution. My main project is named myproject.Web and has a folder Views (with subfolder) where I have all the `cshtml` files. In addition, myproject.Web depends on another project, myproject.UI, which also has a folder Views which contains more `cshtml` that are common to many projects.

The project myproject.Web runs fine when I execute `dotnet run` on the command line. However, when I `dotnet publish` and (in the publish folder) execute `dotnet myproject.Web.dll` the project does not work as expected. The landing page loads in the browser, but when I log in I received HTTP 404 error. After inspection I found that none of the files in the Views folder were being copied. That seems to be the likely source of the problem.

I have managed to get the cshtml files in the UI project into the publish folder, but after all my efforts I cannot get the `cshtml`files in `myproject.Web\Views` into the publish folder.

I post below the relevant parts of my `.csproj` file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Views\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Views\**\*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="PostPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
    <Exec Command="xcopy /E /Y /R  &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\myproject.UI\Views\*&quot; $(PublishDir)Views\*" />
  </Target>
```

**Update**

The comment by Kirk below explains why the `cshtml` files are not being copied. But that does not explain why I get the 404 error. In brief:

1. The 404 does not appear for the login page (it works as expected).
2. The 404 error appears after performing logging.
3. The `dotnet myproject.Web.dll` output does not show any error (copied below for completeness).
4. This behaviour only happens with the published artifact, when executed with `dotnet run` it works perfectly.

`dotnet myproject.Web.dll` output:

```
Hosting environment: Local
Content root path: C:\Projects\Master-Demos\Code\myproject.Web\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\publish
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:57579
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
ContentProvider [Watch]: /Views/Home/../Shared/Widgets/_TileEnriched.cshtml
ContentProvider [GetFileInfo]: /Views/Home/../Shared/Widgets/_TileEnriched.cshtml
ContentProvider [GetFileInfo]: /Views/Home/../Shared/Widgets/_TileEnriched.cshtml
ContentProvider [Watch]: /Views/Home/../Shared/Widgets/_TileEnriched.cshtml
ContentProvider [GetFileInfo]: /Views/Home/../Shared/Widgets/_TileEnriched.cshtml
ContentProvider [GetFileInfo]: /Views/Home/../Shared/Widgets/_TileEnriched.cshtml
```

Comment: Views are precompiled by default in ASP.NET Core 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: I didn't know that. That explains why there is no `cshtml` files in my publish folder, but then why am I getting the 404 error? The dotnet logs do not show any errors (updated question above with those logs).

Comment: I have a similar issue. In debug mode my app works fine but when in my debug\notecoreapp2.0 folder I run dotnet myproject.dll it cannot find the views. I have to copy them to make this work